# Iterating through word document in OpenXml entering text into bookmarks (losing formatting)

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a word document with bookmarks set. The bookmarks are ultra-simple and do not span tables or paragraphs. The following code works but I lose the formatting from the document and the insert uses word's default font & size etc. How can I just enter text into the bookmark keeping the documents formatting?

```
using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFileName, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    var bookmarkStarts = mainPart.Document.Descendants<BookmarkStart>().ToList();

    foreach (BookmarkStart bookmarkStart in bookmarkStarts)
    {
      InsertIntoBookmark(bookmarkStart, "Hello");
    }
}

private static void InsertIntoBookmark(BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string text)
{
    OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();

    while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
    {
        OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
        elem.Remove();
        elem = nextElem;
    }
    Run run = new Run();
    run.Append(new Text(text));
    bookmarkStart.Parent.InsertAfter<Run>(run, bookmarkStart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to directly accomplish what you are trying to achieve in your case. Bookmarks won't hold any formatting information so that when copied will not retain any formatting.

A practical work around is to get the default formatting of the document manually and try to apply it to the paragraph in which your Run is getting inserted.

Instead of using bookmarks, you can also use content controls which will give more additional flexibility in inserting text into a word document using OOXML.

Comment: Unfortunately content controls are not possible as our client still uses word 2003...

Answer (score 0):

One options is to actully replace the text in the Run instead of deleting everything and insert an unformatted Run. The pesky thing about Word however is that it have a habit of inserting multiple Runs for what should be one, and sometimes even splitting a single word into two or more Runs.

I solved this by using the same loop used in your example, but instead of deleting everything, I replace the text in the first Run, and delete the rest until you hit the BookmarkEnd. Things can still go wrong (because Word...) but I find it works good enough, to handle whatever else arises on case to case basis.

Your example reworked to replace instead of delete and insert:

```
private static void InsertIntoBookmark(BookmarkStart bookmarkStart, string text)
        {
            OpenXmlElement elem = bookmarkStart.NextSibling();
            bool firstRunReplaced = false;
            while (elem != null && !(elem is BookmarkEnd))
            {
                OpenXmlElement nextElem = elem.NextSibling();
                if (elem is Run && !firstRunReplaced)
                {
                    ((Run)elem).Elements<Text>().First().Text = text;
                    firstRunReplaced = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    elem.Remove();
                }
                elem = nextElem;
            }
        }
```